# 'Holder/owner of right'

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

Holder/owner of right./ The right is with me.
Is there a noun/or a compound noun in english?
Even an idiom or smth?

Examples:

- We fight, because right is with us/holders/owners of right, and because of that we shall fight and we shall be victors.
- I will not concede or cede my right, how do you want me to, and I am an owner of right.
- Holders of right, no matter how long time stretches, will get their right.

Comment: The person that owns the rights on something is the "rights holder" (or the rights owner). Unless you refer to a specific right, the plural is normally used.

Comment: 'Owner of right' is actually a legal tterm , meaning something different.

Comment: I think the idiom you're looking for is "We have truth on our side."

Answer (score 1):

When we justify military action or violence by appeals to a moral good, we say

> [We have right on our side](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have%20right%20on%20our%20side%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 0):

***A righteous person***  (someone acting or disposed to act rightly or justly; conforming to the precepts of divine law or accepted standards of morality; upright, virtuous. OED)